# How can I use jquery slidetoggle with many content boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some content boxes in my page and I need to toggle some contents under these content boxes.

My content boxes look like this:

```
<div class="package">
    <div class="banner-wrap">
        <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/packages/package1.png" alt=""/>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="event">
            <p class="readmore">read more <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></p>
        </div>

        <div class="more-info">
            <p>----- this is my toggling contents ---- </p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="package">
    <div class="banner-wrap">
        <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/packages/package1.png" alt=""/>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="event">
            <p class="readmore">read more <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></p>
        </div>

        <div class="more-info">
            <p>----- this is my toggling contents ---- </p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="package">
    <div class="banner-wrap">
        <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/packages/package1.png" alt=""/>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="event">
            <p class="readmore">read more <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></p>
        </div>

        <div class="more-info">
            <p>----- this is my toggling contents ---- </p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

What I need is when user click on `.readmore` I want to toggle `.more-info` DIV. This is how I tried it. but its only toggling contents in first content box.

```
$(".readmore").click(function() {
    $(".more_info").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(500, function() {
        $(".readmore").html($(this).is(':visible') ? "read less <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-up'></i>" : "read more <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>");
    });
});
```

Can anybody tell how to modify this code?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3juzc7/1/)**

Comment: Better if you create a demo here in **Snippet** or on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** .

Comment: @divy3993 Thank you, I created a demo with my current code - http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3juzc7/1/

Comment: you can also use bootstrap collapse http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$(".readmore").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings(".more-info").slideToggle().promise().done(function () {
        $this.html($(this).is(':visible') ? "read less <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-up'></i>" : "read more <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>");
    });
});
```

Or simply

```
$(".readmore").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings(".more-info").slideToggle(function () {
        $this.html($(this).is(':visible') ? "read less <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-up'></i>" : "read more <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>");
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49ktpufn/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".readmore").click(function() {
  var txt = $(this).parent().next(".more-info").is(':visible') ? "Read More" : "hide";
  console.log(txt);
  $(this).text(txt).parent().siblings(".more-info").slideToggle()
});
```

```css
.more-info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="package">
  <div class="banner-wrap">
    <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/packages/package1.png" alt="" />
      </a>

    </figure>
    <div class="event">
      <p class="readmore">Read More<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="more-info">
      <p>----- this is my toggling contents ----</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="package">
  <div class="banner-wrap">
    <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/packages/package1.png" alt="" />
      </a>

    </figure>
    <div class="event">
      <p class="readmore">Read More<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="more-info">
      <p>----- this is my toggling contents ----</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="package">
  <div class="banner-wrap">
    <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/packages/package1.png" alt="" />
      </a>

    </figure>
    <div class="event">
      <p class="readmore">Read More<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="more-info">
      <p>----- this is my toggling contents ----</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes its working. but one more question. When I trying to change `read more` text with slidetoggle. It changing all `read more` text.

Comment: This is how I modify your code -  `$(".readmore").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings(".more-info").slideToggle(500, function() {
     $(".readmore").html($(this).is(':visible') ? "read less <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-up'></i>" : "read more <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>");
  });
 });`

Comment: what you want to do ? you want to change read more text on click? and what else?